# When 0 in x is odd, how to assign id value between this zero and the next zero to the new variable ref

Tags: r

```
x<-c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1)
aaa<-data.frame(x)
aaa$id<-1:nrow(aaa)
```

When 0 in x is odd, how to assign id value between this zero and the next zero to the new variable ref.

The results like:

[image]

Comment: Suppose you have 3 0s at the beginning, how would this change.  Also, for the first case, there are two zeros, so not clear whether you are only taking the last row or not?

Answer (score 4):

```
aaa$ref <- with(aaa, ifelse(cumsum(x == 0) %% 2, id, NA))

aaa
#    x id ref
# 1  0  1   1
# 2  0  2  NA
# 3  1  3  NA
# 4  1  4  NA
# 5  0  5   5
# 6  1  6   6
# 7  1  7   7
# 8  1  8   8
# 9  0  9  NA
# 10 1 10  NA
# 11 1 11  NA
# 12 0 12  12
# 13 1 13  13
# 14 1 14  14
```

Comment: Good, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(aaa)[, grp := rleid(x)][, .I[seq_len(.N) == .N  & x==0], grp]$V1
i2 <- unlist(lapply(split(i1, as.integer(gl(length(i1), 2, 
          length(i1)))), function(x) head(x[1]:x[2],-1)))
aaa[!i2, ref := id][, grp := NULL][]
#    x id ref
# 1: 0  1   1
# 2: 0  2  NA
# 3: 1  3  NA
# 4: 1  4  NA
# 5: 0  5   5
# 6: 1  6   6
# 7: 1  7   7
# 8: 1  8   8
# 9: 0  9  NA
#10: 1 10  NA
#11: 1 11  NA
#12: 0 12  12
#13: 1 13  13
#14: 1 14  14
```